# Use Visual Studio Publish Profile to commit and sync a GitHub repo

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, msbuild

I have a VS2013 solution in source control with GitHub.

I created a Publish Profile for one of my projects that copies certain files locally to a DIFFERENT GitHub repo.

I then have to manually commit and sync the changes to the 2nd repo.

What I would like to do if possible, is use my Publish Profile to commit and sync the 2nd repo after copying the new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.pubxml` profile is just an MSBuild file that's imported so you can do a build with `/v:diag` and hook into any of the `OnBefore*` or `OnAfter*` targets logged (e.g. `WebFileSystemPublish` from `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets`) or redefine your own `DependsOn*` property or, even better, since it's inside `.pubxml` and it's not imported unless you select it or specify `/p:PublishProfile=Foo` (although falsy `DeployOnBuild` is ignored) you can hook into standard `AfterBuild` and it won't run on normal `/t:Build`.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\Users\Ilya.Kozhevnikov\Dropbox\Foo\WebApplication1\Foo</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Command>
        <![CDATA[
          pushd "$(publishUrl)"
          git add -A && git commit -m Foo && git push
        ]]>
      </Command>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(Command.Trim())" ContinueOnError="true" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Oh, that's clever. I'm not that familiar with git - I just use the GUI. So I can research various command line options and just call them on the publish directory, right?

Comment: @maxmoore14 sure, given the exe is in your Path.